# What is the difference between "花が開きます" and "花が咲きます"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What is the difference between "花が開きます" and "花が咲きます". I think it's all about flowers blooming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like some other languages such as English, 咲く is the default, specialized verb to describe the phenomenon of flowers opening, or to "bloom", and 開く is not.

At least in the modern language, using 開く for flowers suggests that your focus is not that you simply enjoy a blooming flower, but you have some special interest in the mechanical process of a flower opening because, say, you are a florist that has to control the timing of displaying flower in the store, or a botanist that has to manipulate experiment conditions etc.

Although there is a bookish expression 花開く, it is mostly for "flourish" as a figure of speech. For real flowers we stick to 咲く e.g. 花咲く丘 "a flowering hill".

Answer (score 1):

According to [weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%8A%B1%E9%96%8B%E3%81%8F), they are synonymous with one exception:

花開く (as one unit, not 花が開く) can be used to talk about things other than flowers blooming metaphorically. The example given is "才能が花開く".